# How to use a text_field to input a many_to_many association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to replace a select field with a text_field (to which I'm going to add autocomplete), so that all possible associations don't have to be loaded every time.

This is the form:

```
  <%= form_for(Relation.new) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :dependency_id, :value => @article.id %>
    <%= f.text_field :dependent_title %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

And this is the model:

```
  def dependent_title
    dependent.try(:title)
  end

  def dependent_title=(title)
    self.dependent = Article.find_by_title(title) if title.present?
  end
```

When I type in a title and press "submit" nothing happens.

It seems to work in the rails console:

```
irb(main):024:0> rel.dependent_title=("Optimization")
  Article Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."title" = ? LIMIT ?  [["title", "Optimization"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "Optimization"
irb(main):025:0> rel.dependent_title
=> "Optimization"
irb(main):026:0> rel.dependent_id
=> 479
```

Comment: You defined `dependent_title` but calling `rel.dependency_title`.

Comment: Before I tested it in irb I named it "dependent_title". I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are looking for a field that looks like a text field but does the work of select field and with search option. 
If I've understood your need correctly, you could research on select2 - a jQuery solution to your problem.

https://select2.org/

http://select2.github.io/select2/